# Cannot start openssh in Windows Server 2016

Tags: openssh, windows-server-2016, sshd

I've installed OpenSSH on Windows Server 2016 with the following manual:

[Installing SFTP (SSH FTP) Server on Windows with OpenSSH](http://woshub.com/installing-sftp-ssh-ftp-server-on-windows-server-2012-r2/)

However, I am not able to Start OpenSSH (error 1067). On top of that, sshd does not exist in `services.msc` at all.

```
PS C:\OpenSSH-Win64> .\install-sshd.ps1
[SC] SetServiceObjectSecurity SUCCESS
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig2 SUCCESS
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig2 SUCCESS
sshd and ssh-agent services successfully installed
```

Later then:

```
PS C:\OpenSSH-Win64> Start-Service sshd
Start-Service : Failed to start service 'OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Service sshd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Answer (score 4):

Step 8 of the following helped:
[OpenSSH : Install](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Windows_Server_2016&p=openssh)

> Back to PowerShell and move to OpenSSH installed folder, then run [.\FixHostFilePermission.ps1] like follows.